# How to call a function when a tab is selected in Angular 4 Tabs?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

anyone knows how can I call a function when Tab 1 is selected ?  md-on-select is no more working

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

template html:

```
 <md-tab-group (selectChange)='onSelectChange($event)'>
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'tabs-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'tabs-overview-example.html',
})
export class TabsOverviewExample {
  onSelectChange(event) {
    if(event.index== 0){
      console.log('Tab1 is selected!');
    }else{
      console.log('Tab1 is not selected!')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is being displayed in the console

Comment: i edit the code, try it now :), it should work fine, i tried it.

Comment: Sorry, I inserted (selectChange)='onSelectChange($event)' in <md-tab> instead of <md-tab-group>. It is working now,thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `selectChange` event:

```
<md-tab-group (selectChange)="onTabSelectChange($event)">
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

And in your component:

```
onTabSelectChange(tabChange: MdTabChangeEvent) {
 // do whatever you need to do here
}
```

You can review the docs for [Material Tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api) for more details on `MdTabChangeEvent`

Comment: how to import MdTabChangeEvent please ?

Comment: `import { MdTabChangeEvent } from '@angular/material';`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<md-tab-group #tabgroup (focusChange)="changeTab(tabgroup)">
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

**in ts file**:

```
public changeTab(tabgroup) {
    let pid = tabgroup._currentLabelWrapper.id;     
    let activeTab =$("#"+pid).text().trim();
    console.dir("Active tab: " + activeTab);
}
```

This way you can have any number of tabs and instantly you can get which tab have been currently selected.